# How to use botframework on Azure endpoint to work in your own bot design?

Tags: azure, botframework, messaging, chatbot, endpoint

My question is simple. However, I am unable to find it anywhere on Internet.

I have published my bot on azure. It gives my messaging endpoint as https://something.azurewebsites.net/api/messages (it is not exactly  real).

How can I use this to get and post json files that it should give? The file I will receive, I will hold it on variable and then loop around to get particular messages or post messages. However, it is not work? Do I need to give secret along with this on header? How will this endpoint work so I can give and receive messages through input field on my chatbot design on HTML?

Comment: Have a look to "directline channel"

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

You won't ever need to get or post messages directly. If you have a Bot Channels Registration resource or a Web App Bot resource then that takes care of all communication with your endpoint. Connect your resource to whatever channels you want (like Direct Line) and then use those channels' clients to communicate with the bot. Have a look at the documentation for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0